# Frases con doble negacion

Tags: selección-de-palabras, negación

Siempre he escuchasdo frases como "no sé nada", y me ha traido mucha confusion de cómo debe usarse. La question es que "no sé nada" de hecho indica que "sabes algo". Por ejemplo: "no le eches nada" deberia ser dicho "echale nada" o "no le eches algo", no? A pesar de que estas frases son ampliamente usadas y usarlas de otra forma traeria confusion, estan realmente bien dichas estas frases?